# A finite set of infinite words is $\omega$-regular.

Tags: logic, automata

Prove or disprove : A finite set of infinite words is $ω$-regular.

I am planning to prove this statement by constructing a NBA for every infinite word and then using the closure of $\omega$-regular languages under union.

But I am stuck in trying to show that every infinite word has a NBA or is captured by a LTL formula. Can someone help with regard to this?
Or else should I try to disprove this? Could anyone give some pointers?

Comment: I only read up on the definitions today, but intuition suggests that a single $\omega$-word will rarely, if ever, be the *only* accepted one for some NBA.

Comment: @henno-brandsma Think of $a^\omega$ or $ab^\omega$.

Comment: Only one state and one transition. But more complex words (almost all, topologically) won't work. Is my hunch anyway. No proof as yet, though. @J.-E.Pin

Comment: @henno-brandsma A NBA accepts a single $\omega$-word iff this word is ultimately periodic.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin so the rationals in the Cantor set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Every non-empty $\omega$-regular set contains an ultimately periodic word.

Comment: Added Hint: there exist irrational numbers

Comment: Upvoted and accepted, I got this after so many days today after I read this [answer on MathOverfow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/145378).